# CNAME subdomain redirect to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have a subdomain setup as a CNAME and would like it redirected to a sub directory, unfortunately I haven't done this before and need some help with it.

So it's setup as:

```
support.example.com CNAME example.com
```

We would like it to redirect to:

```
example.com/support/
```

I've tried to put this in the .htaccess file in the public_html of example.com but it's not redirecting and I'm not sure where to go next:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/support/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You want it to redirect the user (he will see `http://example.com/support/index.php` in his address bar) or to point to this folder (the user will see `http://support.example.com` but the file will be loaded from `http://example.com/support/index.php`) ?

Comment: I'd like the user to be redirected to `http://example.com/support/`